# soft Assert is not failing the test case as expected, what to do?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, assert

I have added a verify title breakpoint where soft assertion is comparing two strings which would be two titles, ideally if it is not going to the next page then S1 remains say x and S2 also remains x and then the softAssert s.assertNotEquals(s1,s2) becomes false and the Test case fails with a ITestResult return type as true. But it is not failing the Test Case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assertAll() methods needs to be called at the end if you want the results to be judged as pass or fail. https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/soft-asserts-in-testng-example